# How to execute ActivityBuilder without serializing it?

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

Let's say I have a workflow created progrmatically like this

```
ActivityBuilder<int> ab = new ActivityBuilder<int>();
ab.Name = "Add";
ab.Properties.Add(new DynamicActivityProperty {Name = "Operand1", Type = typeof (InArgument<int>)});
ab.Properties.Add(new DynamicActivityProperty {Name = "Operand2", Type = typeof (InArgument<int>)});
ab.Implementation = new Sequence
        {
            Activities =
                {
                    new WriteLine
                        {
                            Text =
                                new VisualBasicValue<string>(
                                "Operand1.ToString() + \" + \" + Operand2.ToString()")
                        }

                }
        };
```

One way I know to execute it is to first serialize the `ActivityBuilder` object into `XAML`. Next, load the serialized `XAML` using `ActivityXamlServices`. Create a dictionary for parameters. Execute it using `WorkflowInvoker` or `WorkflowApplication`

Is there any way to execute this workflow without the need to convert/serialize activity builder to XAML?

WorkflowApplication and WorkflowInvoker takes an Activity as input for execution. Can I somehow use `activityBuilder.Implementation` directly with `WorkflowApplication` or `WorkflowInvoker`?

Why I want this? Because we have a workflow designer which user uses to create and execute workflow. User also creates workflow progrmatically. Workflow can be up to 80MB in size. This is hurting application's memory due to serialization and de-serialization of 80MB files to and from `XAML`. I want to somehow skip this step and directly execute activity.

Does it makes sense?

Comment: By default VS designer uses ActivityBuilder. I guess you're ysing the rehosted version; I never tried it but can't you just force it to use DynamicActivity instead of ActivityBuilder? Just give a serialization of a empty DynamicActivity to Designer.Text.

Comment: Well, another way to do it at runtime is to transform ActivityBuilder to DynamicActivity. It's just a few lines of code and then you can execute DynamicActivity as you would normally do with WorklowInvoker/WorkflowApplication

Comment: Can you point me to code which do it? I am unable to find it

Comment: I don't have the code. I've never done it myself but it should be really straightforward. You can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.activitybuilder.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.dynamicactivity.aspx) that both ActivityBuilder and DynamicActivity are in all identical but DynamicActivity ihnerits from Activity. The two main things you want to do is to pass ActivityBuilder.Implementation to DynamicActivity.Implementation and loop through ActivityBuilder.Properties and pass them to DynamicActivity.Properties.

Comment: From there on you've an activity ready to be executed, with all arguments and variables exactly as the original ActivityBuilder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use an ActivityBuilder, just create the activities you want and execute them.

```
var wf = new Sequence()
{
    Variables =
    {
        new Variable<int>("Operand1", 7),
        new Variable<int>("Operand2", 42)
    },
    Activities =
    {
        new WriteLine
        {
            Text =
                new VisualBasicValue<string>(
                "Operand1 & \" + \" & Operand2")
        }
    }
};


WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(wf);
```

An example using DynamicActivityProperty:

```
    var wf = new DynamicActivity<int>
    {
        Properties =
         {
            new DynamicActivityProperty { Name = "Operand1", Type = typeof(InArgument<int>) },
            new DynamicActivityProperty { Name = "Operand2", Type = typeof(InArgument<int>) }
         },
        Implementation = () => new Sequence()
            {
                Activities =
                {
                    new WriteLine
                    {
                        Text =
                            new VisualBasicValue<string>(
                            "Operand1 & \" + \" & Operand2")
                    },
                    new Assign<int>
                    {
                        To = new ArgumentReference<int> { ArgumentName = "Result" },
                        Value = new VisualBasicValue<int>("Operand1 + Operand2")
                    }
                }
            }
    };

    var inputs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    inputs["Operand1"] = 7;
    inputs["Operand2"] = 42;
    var output = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(wf, inputs);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: My scenario is a bit complex. I can't change the existing implementation. I need these dynamic properties because they are required in the bigger picture. The scope of variable would be only inside the sequence